# 決して～ない　vs　まったく～ない

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, polarity-items

What is the difference between **決して～ない** and **まったく～ない**?

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely an overlap in the "completely/absolute" domain between 決して...ない and まったく...ない

If we want to split them apart, then Chocolate has a good pair of sentences to help illustrate the difference:

> 「決して忘れません」

= *definitely* don't forget.

決して usually relates to volition or decisional completeness / finality.

Or the opposite of not being committed to remembering.

Command-related usage is quite common for 決して so it also has a kind of [必ず](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-489955) sense.

> 「全くわかりません」

=I don't understand *at all*

Or we could say there's nothing in the contents I understand (the opposite of understanding all of the contents).

まったく relates to completeness of things.

---

A further signal other than looking at usage that tells us 決して is more formal is that 決して depends on the 音読み of [決](https://kakijun.jp/page/07136200.html)　whereas まったく when written in kanji uses one of the 訓読み of 全.

Answer (score 1):

They basically mean the same thing, except the latter is more informal.

Comment: でも・・「全くわかりません」"I don't understand at all",「決して忘れません」"I'll never forget" は、「決してわかりません」「全く忘れません」には言い換えられないですよね・・・

Comment: Hmm, I also thought they mean the same thing, but @Chocolate is right, those are not interchangeable. Maybe contrasting the same verb with those two forms might help think through the subtle difference, like 「決して言わない」 vs 「全く言わない」

Comment: there's also 一切...ない